# Why do governments provide a tax discount for married couples who don't have children?

Tags: taxes

It's perfectly clear to me why the government would provide tax discounts for having children: today's kids are future taxpayers and society wants to incentivize having more of them when birth rates are low. But why provide any benefits whatsoever to people who are merely *married*? Society at large doesn't benefit from people's marriage, it only benefits when the married couple ends up having children.

Or perhaps there are countries that follow exactly this model and only provide incentives for married couples who have children?

Comment: A reminder to please not use comments under the question to provide answers - please write a real answer instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Because every Western country was Christian when tax codes were set up

Christianity is strongly opposed to sex for pleasure. Catholic doctrine (which for a millennia and a half was the only Christian doctrine) is that sex exists only for procreation, and sex for any other reason is sinful. In spite of Biblical examples of polygamy, Christianity fixed on monogamy as the permitted route for procreation. This all carried over into most subsequent Christian sects. And every Western country is or was majority-Christian.

Taxation in a more modern country is not merely about raising money to fight wars. In many cases (carbon taxes, airport taxes, taxes on cigarettes and unhealthy foods, tax breaks on renewable energy) it provides a push through the "invisible hand" of the capitalist economy to promote "good" activities and reduce "bad" activities. If you see sex outside marriage as sinful, then tax breaks to encourage people to marry are simply obvious.

Most historically-Christian countries now have policies driven by secular principles, rather than the (fairly arbitrary) biases of a particular sect. Some aspects of this history often still remain though, like shop opening times on Sundays - or like tax breaks for married people. In time it seems likely that these will fade away, but the spreading secularisation of the West is an ongoing process that's taken hundreds of years to get to this point. In the meantime you can expect odd corner cases like this all over the place.

And some countries (most notably the US) are a lot further behind on secularisation than others. In those cases, some minor inequality in the tax code is a trivial inconvenience compared to institutional racism and sexism.

Comment: "Christianity is strongly opposed to sex for pleasure." Citation needed.

Comment: @EvilSnack Would Wikipedia do? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_theology_of_sexuality The Catholic church considers all sexual acts automatically sinful which are not within marriage *and* could not lead to pregnancy.

Comment: @Graham: That's the *Catholic* church, though.  Many Protestants don't place the same value on celibacy (and don't require it for their clergy).

Comment: @dan04 I didn't mention celibacy. The Protestant churches all historically shared exactly the same opinion of sex and marriage as the Catholic church, namely that sex outside marriage was a sin. Current secular Christianity is different, of course, but my point was that this tax break is an artifact of the state's historical religion.

Comment: @Graham [Sexual abuse of children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church_sexual_abuse_cases) seems to be fine according to the catholic church, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil True, but off topic from the OP.  I had to work fairly hard to keep the answer on topic without getting onto that kind of thing. :)

Comment: @dan04 Some protestants do require celibacy and remember, the Catholic Church was once an authoritarian theocracy that ran Europe!

Answer (score 35):

There probably is no general answer - the tax discount for married couples greatly differs in different tax systems and probably has a different motivation in every system. Some motivations that are often given (not that I necessarily agree with them) are:

- Marriage, in general, is good for society, because it provides stability, reduces promiscuity, etc.
- Married partners generally will (and often must) financially support each other, so married people are less likely to have to resort to welfare programs.
- Most married couples will end up having children, so this supports children, too.

---

In particular, in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany), the main tax advantage of being married is the availability of [income splitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_splitting) - which simply means that the income of married couples will be taxed as if each partner earned exactly half of the total income. This provides a tax advantage (because income tax is progressive) which grows the more different the actual incomes of the partners are.

This is usually justified by claiming that married couples typically share their income anyway, and the state should not influence a couple's decision on how they split their work. For example, the political party FDP says:

> Warum geht es beim Ehegattensplitting auch um die Freiheit des eigenen
> Lebensmodells?
>
> Kritiker des Splittingtarifs argumentieren oft damit, dass
> herkömmliche Arbeitsaufteilungen in Familien aufgebrochen werden
> müssten. Es geht den Staat aber nichts an, wie Paare sich die
> Verantwortung für Arbeit und Familie aufteilen.

Translation (by me):

> Why is income splitting also about the freedom to choose one's own path in life?
>
> Critics of the income-splitting system often argue, that the traditional distribution of work in families must be broken up. However, it should not concern the state how families distribute the responsibility for work and family.

*Source: [FDP - Faire Steuern für Paare – Ehegattensplitting beibehalten](https://www.fdp.de/seite/faire-steuern-fuer-paare-ehegattensplitting-beibehalten)*

Comment: The actual reason in Germany is that many voters profit from it and removing it would be unpopular with them. Married couples without children were an exception when this tax regulation was established as were woman with an independent income.

Comment: A law from which "many voters" profit from, sounds like government working as intended.

Comment: @Mavrik: They only profit on the surface and unfairly so. The tax income just has to come from somewhere else.

Comment: *Married partners generally will (and often must) financially support each other, so married people are less likely to have to resort to welfare programs.* If that is a reason, then we should reduce taxes on rich people, then...

Comment: *Most married couples will end up having children, so this supports children, too.* That supports giving tax discounts to couples with children, not to childless couples.

Comment: I'm not trying to imply anything, just asking a question intended to be taken literally. Why is reducing promiscuity good for society?

Comment: @Vaelus I'd venture to guess it keeps the number of unexpected mothers, single parents and STD rates lower, all of which are more prevalent in lower income communities, adding avoidable costs to government services. It also lessens the burden of medical services which raises the overall capacity of the health care system, which if government funded, also lessens cost, but even in a privatized system, lowers the number of uninsured people in hospitals unable to foot the bill.

Comment: *Some* US states have “community property” laws with the effect of allowing married couples to claim German-style “income splitting”.   Our federal government originally introduced joint filings (based on the couple's total income, not their two individual incomes), so that all married couples could claim income splitting regardless of their state.

Comment: To keep it fair, married couples not only have *advantages*, they also have *disadvantages*. If married people were being treated as single in respect to taxes, it would only be fair they were treated as singles in the parts where they have responsibilities because of marriage. For example if the wife is longtime unemployed, but the husband works, she basically gets nothing. If they were both single, the government would pay her welfare money. So you cannot just remove the benefits of marriage but keep the drawbacks. It's either both or none.

Comment: @nvoigt I believe if a German unmarried couple lives together, they do *not* get the tax advantages that a married couple gets, but they *do* get the same welfare disadvantages as a married couple.

Comment: @Vaelus: I do not know, I am just citing arguments I read. I believe the opposition to promiscuity mostly comes from moral or religious objections to it, but there may be other reasons.

Comment: @Jan: Yes, that is true - the term is *Einstehensgemeinschaft* - basically if a couple looks like they are supporting each other, both incomes will be considered before one partner can claim welfare payments. Living together is not enough, but e.g. living together for >1 year is, unless you can demonstrate you are only "roommates" (by e.g. showing separate bank accounts, cooking meals separately etc.).

Comment: @SJuan76 "If that is a reason, then we should reduce taxes on rich people, then" - that would make sense if being rich were a choice that people could just decide on one day

Answer (score 22):

In part, this discount is a hold-over from when marriage implied two people living on one income: i.e., husband as sole breadwinner, with wife as a fiscal dependent. This extra dependency (in addition to any child dependents) justified the tax incentive. Of course, single-income, male-breadwinner families are far rarer these days, with only certain income classes being able to afford that arrangement, and only certain religious conservatives finding the arrangement attractive. These days the marriage exemption is touted as either:

- An effort to incentivize traditional marriage practices, or...
- An acknowledgement that married couples often have somewhat higher expenditures given the change in life circumstances (e.g., home ownership, and the implication of a desire for parenthood)

I'm not sure the marriage exemption is still meaningful (except for traditional relationships), but trying to eliminate or overly-modify it would create a political firestorm that that no one really wants to face.

Comment: Yes, there are fewer single-income households then there used to be. But there are still a lot, and it's not always by choice, and certainly not always because of religious conservatism. Also it doesn't have to be a "sole breadwinner" situation, it could be that one partner's pay is much less. You're right, not everyone can afford it, but they still find themselves in that situation.

Comment: @Nacht for example, in many families one spouse has to work part time in order to take care of children

Comment: @Esther And even if they don't work part-time, it's still true that women generally earn less for the same jobs. Although by that logic we should just give tax breaks to women in general (I guess we kind of do, since the tax is based on the earnings).

Comment: @Barmar when adjusted for job types and years of experience, the wage gap nearly completely disaappears.

Comment: @JonathanReez: As someone who's done actual research on this, I can tell you that's not true. Studies carefully control for those variables. It's better in low-paying jobs (where adjusted income is pretty close for women and men) but the higher the status and income potential of a job, the greater the gender disparity. Crap-jobs are egalitarian; good jobs aren't.

Answer (score 12):

> But why provide any benefits whatsoever to people who are merely married?

Altough the discussion often centres around children, that's wide off the mark.

It's simple: **With responsibility come privileges.**

When married, you are responsible to pay

- your partner's livelihood before a social safety net kicks in
- a nursing home
- your spouse's funeral
- your deceased spouse's debts if you don't reject the complete heritage within 6 weeks [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Now, if all you got out of an official state marriage would be responsibilities, who would do that? You could stay unmarried and skirt the financial obligations.

> Society at large doesn't benefit from people's marriage

This premise is wrong, as society does indeed benefit from one marital partner taking care of the other.

Comment: Who pays for debts. nursing homes, and the funeral of a single person?

Comment: @DKNguyen in Germany, nursing homes are covered by "Pflegeversicherung" (a special part of mandatory health insurance that applies to long term care, standard medical care is still covered by health insurance)  and personal assets, if any, or by close relatives (parents or children) if any, else by social security. Debts are part of the estate, so they have to be paid by the beneficiaries, and if none the state will take over the estate and covers as much debt as covered by the estate.. Funeral is paid for by relatives, if there are none by the estate, if there is none by social security.

Comment: I can confirm this from own experience (my wife died after long illness, and apart from the horrors of the experience there was also a lot of cost), but it is worth pointing out that there would be other ways to help with that (and in fact there are other ways - e.g. there is substantial tax credit if you care for a disable relative or spouse), and it is probably fair to say that the people who came up with this originally thought this would mostly apply to the combination working husband/housewife.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I appreciate you answering but I'd prefer an answer from the poster because a lot the points made don't really hold up if both individuals in the marriage are self-supporting.

Comment: When a single person is unable to provide for their own livelihood, the state pays.

Comment: @DKNguyen the answer reiterates broadly the view of the German supreme court, so even if you dont find it convincing it is still a correct answer. What is missing is some of the context - two ministries could not agree if married couples should be taxed jointly or separately (both things happened, depending on where the wife was employed), and the compromise was the "Ehegattensplitting" (taxing the couple as if both earned half of the family income, which reversed the negative effect of progressive taxation).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps just to win some votes.

In the United Kingdom in 2013, then-Prime Minister David Cameron announced [a tax break for married couples](https://ifs.org.uk/articles/new-tax-break-some-married-couples), which allows one married partner to transfer up to 10% of their tax-free allowance (the amount of income that is not subject to income tax; then £10,500 per year) to the other partner, if the other partner is taxed at the basic rate (20%).

That's a complicated way of saying that, essentially, if one partner is working (but not earning too much) and the other has little or no income, then the couple together could save up to £210 a year on their income tax bill (now £252 a year due to increases in the tax-free allowance). That's not a lot; it affected only about a third of married couples in the country, and the benefit was £4 per week (now £5). It's rather doubtful that such a small financial difference would enter into a couple's decision to get married.

But that wasn't the point. Cameron's public messaging about the tax break was not about the amount of money, or about encouraging people to get married. According to him (quoted in [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/11423799/David-Cameron-Married-couples-are-the-bedrock-of-society.html), emphasis mine):

> “This policy is about far more than pounds and pence. It’s about **valuing commitment**,” Mr Cameron added. “Families are the bedrock of our society. It’s families who raise our children, look after our old and keep our country going. And this tax change is about **saying as a society, we recognise that**.”

Similar language appeared in the party's [2010 manifesto](https://general-election-2010.co.uk/2010-general-election-manifestos/Conservative-Party-Manifesto-2010.pdf) (page 41, emphasis mine):

> We will recognise marriage and civil partnerships in the tax system in the next Parliament. This will **send an important signal that we value couples** and the commitment that people make when they get married.

So it was about making a statement that his government valued a certain segment of society, rather than achieving an economic outcome. Or in other words, it was about communicating with voters.

Perhaps more tellingly, despite the policy being decided upon in 2010 and formally announced in 2013, the tax change was timed to come into effect in April 2015, only one month before [the next general election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_United_Kingdom_general_election) was to take place.

Answer (score 4):

This is a relict from times when only man was working. Tax was calculated from the family income, but a woman was not expected to make any notable part of it.

Fixing this historical nonsense is difficult because additional taxes now paid by married couples then must be paid by other groups that oppose. Switzerland [failed to pass](https://www.loc.gov/item/global-legal-monitor/2016-03-11/switzerland-rejection-of-abolishment-of-marriage-tax-penalty-and-constitutional-definition-of-marriage/) a referendum.

Comment: Interesting that it’s apparently the opposite problem in Switzerland.

Comment: Not always true. The German system was introduced because *more* women worked. Originally a married couple would pay the same amount of taxes as an individual with the same income, which was a serious disadvantage. See https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehegattensplitting

Answer (score 4):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

We don't.

We have three kinds of relationships

- *concubinage* (= people are/live together without any legal consequences)
- *PACS* (= civil contract)
- marriage (= civil contract with more possibilities financially)

The last two are very close, tax wise.

What gives you extra tax relief are children, each counts as 1/2 human (obviously the ones who decided this never had children...) and applies to the parent(s) to whom children are attached to.
In other words, if you are a family of 4, you are seen as 1 + 1 + 2*0.5 = 3 items.

Comment: This is quite different to the UK. We have the same three categories to which you refer but the tax system is entirely deaf and blind to marriage. Husbands and wives, or civil partners, are taxed entirely independently of one another. There is no relief whatever for children, though a small automatic benefit is paid independently of the tax system for the first two children in a family. Nothing is paid for the third and subsequent children.

Comment: @WS2: so are there any formal advantages of being married? (heritage, ability to get information at the hospital as "family" - these are the ones I can think of for France)

Comment: There are no obvious advantages so far as income or capital gains tax is concerned - but inheritance tax is another area altogether. There are plenty of other non-tax-related advantages in marriage, such as the ones to which you refer.

Answer (score 3):

Arguably governments are pandering symbolically to a wealthier section of the electorate who still actually get married.

The tax allowance often isn't very significant, and even over decades would scarcely defray the most basic expenses of the marriage itself.

But it's also possible governments see it as somewhat financially desirable that people declare their relationships to the state, form stable and long-lasting relationships, and that couples assume joint legal and financial responsibility for each other.

This potentially avoids for example social security payments during brief spells of unemployment (if there are two earners), and avoids some health-related and old-age care costs.

Comment: If you refused this tax split, you’d have to pay benefits to a very poor person who is married to a very rich person, so that person can live without starving.

Comment: @gnasher729: This isn't true. In the UK, for example, taxation is done at the individual level but to claim benefits you are assessed as a couple (whether married or not).

Comment: @JackAidley, the technical term in social security law is "living together as a married couple" (or formerly, living together as husband and wife, "LTAHAW"). The problem is that for those who aren't in fact married, determining who is living together at any given moment, and what the nature of that living together is, is quite a tricky question whenever the state is trying to screw people into the ground, and so the couple have an interest in misrepresenting their relationship, and poverty tends to make relationships unstable anyway. (1/2)

Comment: Also with regard to taxation, it is predominantly individual, but there are some concessions to married and unmarried couples. These concessions include some transfers of allowances possible between the married, and how some very little jobs are effectively untaxed (and exempt from NI) which is a concession to maintained homemakers who do a little bit of work for pocket money, but the NI cuts back in regressively once the earner is working more than a few hours a week. (2/2)

Comment: @gnasher729 But then that very rich person would also be taxed at a rate for almost double the income they would be if taxed together.  Depending on the benefits, how the tax brackets are structured, and the very rich person's income, this could cost taxpayers money, or earn them money.

Comment: Can you provide some reference to this surprising assertion that only wealthier people "still actually get married"? The best I could dig up was [numbers from the BLS](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2013/article/marriage-and-divorce-patterns-by-gender-race-and-educational-attainment.htm), which don't seem to show that at all.

Comment: @T.E.D. - On the one hand, it's actually true that in some countries (neither the question nor the answer specifies), [wealthier people are more likely to be married](https://www.brookings.edu/articles/middle-class-marriage-is-declining-and-likely-deepening-inequality/). On the other hand...[well](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6595/is-this-a-left-wing-site-be-honest#comment16669_6595), [reach your own conclusions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63816416#63816416)

Comment: @Obie2.0 - I won't sit here and say that the USA should be the default nation when one isn't specified. However, if you make an assertion here, don't specify a country, don't provide any supporting references, and it manifestly is **not true** in the USA when I try to dig up references myself, then I do think its fair to say your post is wrong in some respect, and needs fixing so that set of conditions no longer holds.

Comment: @T.E.D. - No, I think it is not at all fair to say that my post is wrong. What is more, I am *certain* that once you read this comment carefully, you will agree with me.

Comment: @Obie2.0, I don't necessarily see the topical connection, but it's great to have someone willing to advertise my views to a broader audience!

Comment: @T.E.D., this was just the first result of a search for "marriage by class": https://ionainstitute.ie/mind-the-gap-how-marriage-and-family-differ-by-social-class-2/, and this is another: https://ifstudies.org/blog/the-marriage-divide-how-and-why-working-class-families-are-more-fragile-today

Comment: OK, but that's a study from *Ireland*, as near as I can tell only surveying Irish people. That would be fair if the question or the answer explicitly said "In Ireland" (heck, I might even be willing to let an "In Europe" slide) *and* if that study were edited into the answer, but it doesn't, and it isn't. Still isn't.

Comment: @T.E.D., the second link concerned America. My point is that this notion that the poor no longer marry as much in the Anglophone world is easily supported by research. Attacks on poor workers have not only undermined existing relationships, but it has eroded the culture of marriage, and certainly made it clear to people at the very bottom that you don't want to be unambiguously declaring your relationship status to the state.

Answer (score 3):

A general philosophy of taxation in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) (and elsewhere) is that things that operate as an economic unit are taxed as a unit. For example if half of a company has mainly expenses and the other half is making profit, only profit after expenses gets taxed; after all the expenses may be necessary for the profit. Or if I am buying office equipment so I can do my job, I may tax-deduct it (with some restrictions).

Now, **the tax benefits in question treat a married couple as such an economic unit**. This in turn is based on the assumption that married partners have a high level of trust in each other and share everything. For example, if one partner focuses more on running the household such that the other partner can put some extra focus on their job to earn more, this is seen as happening within the unit. From this perspective, the tax benefits are not benefits but avoid couples being disproportionately affected by tax progression, etc.

If we suddenly stopped allowing married couples to be taxed as a unit, this would lead to some weird incentives, for example:

- To start simple, let’s consider the tax on gains from financial investments. Right now, these are not taxed below 1000 € (of gains) for a single person and 2000 € for a couple. Therefore, for a married couple, it doesn’t matter which partner owns their financial assets. If the couple were not treated as a unit and taxed separately, they would benefit from splitting their assets in such a manner that the prospected gains are equally distributed.
- Suppose, I get a new job while my spouse is unemployed. Without taxing couples as a unit, it would be advantageous if my new employer hired both of us half time (for half the income) instead, although I do all the work. And a sufficiently shady employer might actually do this for part of our tax gains.
- Suppose I work full time, while my spouse is unemployed and running the household, taking care of our children, etc. Without taxing couples as a unit, I could reduce the taxes we pay as follows: I hire my spouse as a housekeeper any nanny and pay her with part of my income. At first glance, this would increase the taxes we pay due to double taxation: What I pay my spouse gets taxed as my income as well as theirs. However, I can tax-deduce expenses for a housekeeper, nanny, etc. to a certain extent. Thus, I can avoid double taxation and benefit from equalising our incomes and being less affected by tax progression. Figuring out the optimal wage I pay my spouse is left as an exercise to the reader.

In all these examples, I can at least partially restore the tax benefits for couples, but I create a lot of bureaucracy, pointless work, etc. In particular, couples who have enough time at their hand to do these kinds of things benefit without creating anything of value in the process.

Finally mind that I am merely describing the rationale, not fully endorsing it. Some of its assumptions as well as the choice of a marriage (instead of a family) as an economic unit are debatable. Also, many of the above problems can arguably be resolved by changing the respective parts of the tax system – which leads to another reason why this exists: We have a complex tax system that is organically grown to compensate for all kinds of things and the benefits for couples are arguably one of them and made other compensations unnecessary. It would thus not be a good idea to abolish those benefits in isolation – you would have to overhaul the entire system.

Comment: Arguably, paying people for taking care of children might be a way to highlight how much this is actually worth (and giving your spouse some social security insurance, too). Might not be the worst thing to do, especially if you and your spouse break up at some point.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Indeed. However, if that’s the way to implement this, it should be as easy as possible, if not even automatic in certain cases. Also mind that the social security system already does account for this to some extent, although arguably not enough.

Answer (score 2):

**The tax benefit for having a child only kicks in after you choose to have a child - the process of having a child also would take money, and the decision to have a child implies savings for the child, which costs money**

Marriage helps with child rearing in a few ways - it helps in reducing the need for paternity tests, ideally providing multiple incomes to support the child (Whether through a marriage, or through a child support alimony post-divorce, either way works out to some extent), and helps with determining family names for an ancestral record of who is related to whom.

But there's a problem with only providing tax refund on having a child - there's costs incurred to have a child (Some of which mostly apply to having a planned child more than an unplanned one, but nonetheless, still exist as a cost):

1.) They need the free time to engage in the act of sexual reproduction;

2.) They're going to incur multiple costs of pregnancy tests, and the follow-up appointments that come from needing an ultrasound/additional healthcare;

3.) The amount of food they're going to eat during the 9 months pregnancy period will likely increase;

4.) They'll want additional things to have at their home when the child is born;

5.) Any miscarriages or unplanned abortions that happen would effectively make all the above for nothing, and would require trying *again* and incurring all the costs again (If they really want that tax benefit, or if they just want a child for non-tax benefit reasons.);

6.) If they do in fact have the child, now they have maternity and paternity leave often being used to care for the newborn baby, and there are additional costs involved.

Most married couples that plan to have children will, if they aren't able to save up to prepare for those costs, simply not have a child (Or perhaps they'll just adopt or foster a child - but that's not the usual reason for a tax benefit for children.). Tax benefits of simply being married, however, would allow married couples that plan to have children save up more as a result of the tax benefit of being married.

Comment: Then it would make sense to stop providing marriage benefits to people over the age of 45.

Comment: @JonathanReez: To be fair, that's ignoring the possibility of freezing eggs and sperm for IVF later on, though that in itself can incur additional costs.

Comment: "Then it would make sense to stop providing marriage benefits to people over the age of 45. "  If there's a tax benefit to being divorced then that just encourages divorce.  That's not saying these couples would live any differently, they'd just no longer be married on paper for tax purposes.  I get the idea but consider the cost savings to the government in having married couples filing a single joint return vs. them filing two separate returns.  Take whatever it costs to process that extra tax return, split it down the middle, then give that much money to those filing a joint return.  Win!

Comment: @MacGuffin: The part about having joint returns brings to mind another point - having to means test the tax discount in this case is probably not worth the effort, especially if one person hits 45 and the other person in the marriage doesn't.

Comment: @jonthanreez - And here I am paying for college while over 60... Having and supporting kids isn't a once and done thing, and having kids happens across a broad range of parent ages.

Answer (score 1):

[poland](/questions/tagged/poland)

It used to be the other way round in Poland - you had to pay extra taxes if you did not have children. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_tax):

> Introduced *Bykowe*, which was a tax on childlessness that included a tax on those unmarried above 21 years from January 1, 1946 to November 29, 1956. It was later extended to those over 25 years of age until January 1, 1973 when it was repealed.